# Reactive UI Sharing Observable Logic

Tags: reactiveui

I'm trying to set a specific error message if cetain conditions on input text are not met.

Basically if the input url is empty, I want to set ErrorHint to "Server URL cannot be empty"

If the input url does not start with https ErrorHint should be "Server URL must start with https"

Otherwise the ErrorHint should be an empty string.

The below code works, but I feel like I'm replicating logic in my observables. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
        // invalid if the server url is empty
        var serverUrlEmptyObservable =
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.NewServerUrl)
                .Where(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);

        // invalid if the url is not empty but does not start with https
        var serverUrlInvalidPrefixObservable =
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.NewServerUrl)
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .Where(x => !x.StartsWith(NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix));

        // valid if the server url is not empty and starts with proper prefix
        var validServerUrlObservable =
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.NewServerUrl)
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .Where(x => x.StartsWith(NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix));

        // set error message based on which observable fires
        ErrorHint = Observable.Merge(
            validServerUrlObservable.Select(x => ""), 
            serverUrlInvalidPrefixObservable.Select(x => $"Server URL must start with {NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix}"), 
            serverUrlEmptyObservable.Select(x => "Server URL cannot be empty"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one IObservable and use the ToProperty method to set the value of the ErrorHint output property. This is basically how to implement this the "ReactiveUI" way:

```
public class ReactiveViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private const string NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix = "https";

    public ReactiveViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.NewServerUrl)
            .Select(_ =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewServerUrl))
                    return "Server URL cannot be empty";
                else if (!NewServerUrl.StartsWith(NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix))
                    return $"Server URL must start with {NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix}";

                return string.Empty;
            }).ToProperty(this, x => x.ErrorHint, out _errorHint);
    }

    private string _newServerUrl;
    public string NewServerUrl
    {
        get { return _newServerUrl; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _newServerUrl, value); }
    }

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _errorHint;
    public string ErrorHint { get { return _errorHint.Value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the logic by putting it inside a single `Select` function:

```
ErrorHint = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.NewServerUrl)
    .Select(url => 
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url)) 
        {
            return "Server URL cannot be empty";
        }
        if(!url.StartsWith(NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix))
        {
            return $"Server URL must start with {NewServerUrlRequiredPrefix}";
        }
        return "";
    })
    .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

This is simply mapping each `NewServerUrl` value to an appropriate error message, and then only notifying observers when an error message changes (using `DistinctUntilChanged`).